# Anadroid NavController clear back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack

I have 3 fragments but naviagate to one with multiple args.
Example: A -> B -> B-> B-> C 
How can I go to first B fragment?

Answer (score 0):

**Use This**     `Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace
(R.id.frame, new B()).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: Is there any way achieve it using AndroidX NavController - navigate without add to back stack or clear last fragment from stack after navigate?

Comment: that time use "add" instead of "replace".